# Unsupported Java encoding for writing wsdl file

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, wildfly

when deploying the following webservice

```
@WebService(serviceName = "TestService")
@SOAPBinding(use = Use.LITERAL, style = Style.DOCUMENT, parameterStyle= SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public class KekeDummyWebservice implements kekeService {...
```

on one of my servers I do get the following error:

```
javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException:faultCode=CONFIGURATION_ERROR: Unsupported Java encoding for writing wsdl   file: 'ISO8859_15'.
```

I don't know where the 'ISO8859_15' encoding comes from. The wildfly prints out

```
-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-15
```

while starting. Another point is that during wildfly start the warning

```
 [jacorb.codeset] (MSC service thread 1-7) Warning - unknown codeset (ISO8859_15) - defaulting to ISO-8859-1
```

can be seen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on our system, with following error in the log during deployment on Wildlfy10:

> Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=CONFIGURATION_ERROR: Unsupported Java encoding for writing wsdl file: 'Cp1252'

Finally it was solved by resaving of xsd/wsld in utf-8 and setting targetNamespace in WS implementaion accordingly to what was defined in xsd/wsld. This aproach is not fully applicable on your case, but maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run command "locale". It will give "LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-15".
Update this **LANG** to use "en_US.UTF-8" using export.

This solved the issue.